# Atributo do tipo HashMap aparece como Object

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, hashmap

Estou utilizando o framework Spring e os repositórios, e em uma das interfaces de um desses repositórios tenho, por exemplo, um método dessa maneira:

```
@Query("select extract(month from u.atributo1), coalesce(sum(u.atributo2), 0) from #{#entityName} u where extract(year from u.atributo1) = extract(year from current_date()) group by extract(month from u.atributo1)")
public List<HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>> getDoisAtributos();
```

Foi criado o Service que implementa esse método da interface Repository em uma função e logo depois o Controller instância esse Service e chama o método responsável por resgatar os valores do banco de dados a partir do método do service que chama então essa função do repositório.

Porém esperava que no atributo do tipo `List` aparecesse um Array com os atributos do tipo `HashMap` porém aparece os atributos sendo do tipo `Object` e quando percorro os atributos com um foreach por exemplo ou até mesmo com um for estoura um erro falando que não foi possível fazer cast de `Object` para `HashMap`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução para esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma TypedQuery não seria uma possível solução para o seu caso? Já que você criaria uma classe que simularia o comportamento do HashMap.

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia sobre o `TypedQuery` e sua resposta leva a links quanto a solução que encontrei.

Comment: TypedQuery é mais um dos recursos que auxiliam na nossa vida de desenvolvimento. Fico feliz em ter ajudado, mesmo que de forma indireta.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, foi alterado o método da Interface ficando dessa maneira:

```
@Query("select new Map(extract(month from u.atributo1), coalesce(sum(u.atributo2), 0)) from #{#entityName} u where extract(year from u.atributo1) = extract(year from current_date()) group by extract(month from u.atributo1)")
public List<HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>> getDoisAtributos();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]